# How to Ebay oauth process for Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, https, oauth

I have managed to achieve HTTP requests with Volley to an API without auth, but with Ebay API things are becoming harder.

https://github.com/eBay/ebay-oauth-android-client

The above link has the an example, yet it is not filled with a real case scenario.

```
    ApiSessionConfiguration.initialize
    (
        apiEnvironment = ApiEnvironment.PRODUCTION,
        apiConfiguration = ApiConfiguration(
            "<Client ID>",
            "<Redirect Uri>",
            "<space separated scopes>"
        )
    )
```

- Client ID appears on Ebay Developer Account as is and i guess "XXXX-XXXX-PRD-XXXX-XXXX" something on that lines is correct.
- Redirect Uri on the other hand seems more confusing. Which string needs to be placed there? The "RuName" that is similar to the Client ID XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX? Or something like "http://..."?
- Space separated scopes hopefully are; "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing.readonly" + " " + "https://api.ebay.com/oauth/api_scope/sell.marketing" ... and so on.

I have further doubts about the part that requires having a second activity to be overriden on the manifest but i guess that will be better asked separatedly.